# A field has a unique algebraic extension of each degree if and only if its absolute Galois group is the profinite completion of integers

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, profinite-groups

I would like to know how to prove that a field $K$ which has a unique algebraic extension of each degree has its absolute Galois group isomorphic to the profinite completion of the integers $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

One can probably reduce the problem to showing that the Galois groups of finite algebraic extensions of $K$ of each degree is a cyclic group, but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I found it [here](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1985b/GSchemes.pdf), $2.2$: "Let $K$ be a field with separable closure $K_s$. Then the absolute Galois group of $K$ is procyclic (see Exercise 2.11) if and only if $K$ has, for any positive integer $n$, at most one extension of degree $n$ within $K_s$; and that it is isomorphic to $\widehat{\Bbb Z}$ if and only if $K$ has, for any positive integer $n$, exactly one extension of degree $n$ within $K_s$."